Is it possible to cancel GNOME's power off end session dialog using DBUS?
The object org.gnome.SessionManager.EndSessionDialog has a Close method which does actually close the dialog. However, the background timer will keep ticking and after 60 seconds (GNOME 42) it will power off the machine.
Ultimately what I want to achieve is a way to programmatically cancel the 60 seconds delayed shutdown which was triggered by a power button press.
I am aware of the inhibitors locks and don't believe that's the right direction.

why not find the pid and kill that?

I don't believe the dialog has one. It is part of the shell so going that direction will require restarting the shell.

I ended up giving up on the DBUS approach and used a workaround which emulates an ESC keystroke using /dev/uinput.
For anyone who's interested, this is a simplified class which can send keys using /dev/uinput.
